# Updating PHP on Ubuntu 12.04 with Parallels Plesk

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, nginx

I've tried a few times to update php on my server from version 5.3 to the latest 5.5 with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

It seems to work fine but it also updates Apache which I think is modified for plesk and caused it to stop working. I tried to removing Apache with purge and re-installing it but it deleted Plesk and I ended up re-installing everything.

Ideally I'd rather just run nginx with php-fpm without apache but it's not as straightforward anymore with plesk and I have no idea how to go about updating PHP?

I've got a clean install of Parallels Plesk v12.0.18_build1200140606.15 running on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use this ppa instead, which doesn't upgrade apache, but only upgrades php to 5.4:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable